# Problems with foreign keys in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I am trying to link both these tables with a foreign key. But I keep getting error message "ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails " the foreign key is pwalk_id to walk_id

```
Walk Table
walk_id INT(11) PK NN AI
walk_title NN walk_dur INT(11)
walk_spoint VARCHAR(20)
walk_fpoint VARCHAR(20)
walk_desc TEXT NN

Programme Table
prog_id INT(11) PK NN
pwalk_id INT(11) NN
prog_date DATE NN
prog_stime VARCHAR (9) NN
prog_max INT(11)
```

**Edit:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Walk` (
  `walk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `walk_title` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `walk_dur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `walk_spoint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `walk_fpoint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `walk_desc` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`walk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `Programme` (
  `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pwalk_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prog_date` date NOT NULL,
  `prog_stime` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `prog_max` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prog_id`),
  KEY `Progwalk_idx` (`pwalk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you put the output from `show create table <table>;` For both tables please....

Comment: Rodrigo, I am pretty new to this and not sure how you do that

Comment: Well, you can use mysql command to connect to DB, or whatever you use to manage it and execute the SQL query I asked

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Just worked out what the issue was, I had left data in the programme table, DOH!!!